# Authenticate facebook login with "Assert in selenium"

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, testng, facebook-login

I'm writing a testscript to login facebook. Everything was fine until I used Assert to verify that login. I do not understand why the script does not work. Please help me.
Thanks and Respect!

testng, eclipse, selenium_webdriver

```
 package Demo;
 import org.openqa.selenium.By;
 import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
 import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
 import org.testng.Assert;
 import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
 import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
 import org.testng.annotations.Test;

 public class loginface {
        WebDriver driver;
        String actualtitle = driver.getTitle();
        String exceptedtitle = "My Accout";
 public void login(String userName, String password) {  
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    driver.get("http://fb.com");
    driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys(userName);
    driver.findElement(By.id("pass")).sendKeys(password);
    driver.findElement(By.id("loginbutton")).click();
}

@BeforeMethod
public void setUp(){
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
}

@Test
public void loginpass() {
    login("nhokcon2502@gmail.com", "   123!@#");
    Assert.assertEquals(actualtitle, exceptedtitle);
}

@Test
public void loginfail1() {
    login("", "");
    Assert.assertEquals(actualtitle, exceptedtitle);
}

@Test
public void loginfail2() {
    login("abc@gmail.com", "12345678");
    Assert.assertEquals(actualtitle, exceptedtitle);
}
@AfterMethod
public void tearDown() {
    driver.close();
}
```

}

Comment: Please post error stack trace

Answer (score 1):

Please try.

```
Assert.assertEquals(driver.getTitle(), exceptedtitle);
```

Hope you know that whenever you use actualtitle, "driver.getTitle();" does not get called.

```
    String actualtitle = driver.getTitle();
```